# how endl mainly affects fully buffered streams?

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, cout, ostream

https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

In the following site, just before cin heading, it is stated that

> The endl manipulator produces a newline character, exactly as the insertion of '\n' does; but it also has an additional behavior: the stream's buffer (if any) is flushed, which means that the output is requested to be physically written to the device, if it wasn't already. **This affects mainly fully buffered streams, and cout is (generally) not a fully buffered stream.**

My questions are, why endl mainly affects the fully buffered streams, and how cout is not a fully buffered stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three main buffering strategies used for output streams:

1. No buffering - Every write to the stream is immediately written to the underlying output device.
2. Line buffering - Writes to the stream are stored in memory until a newline character is written or the buffer is full, at which point the buffer is flushed to the underlying output device.
3. Full buffering - Writes to the stream are stored in memory until the stream's internal buffer is full, at which point the buffer is flushed to the underlying output device.

---

> why endl mainly affects the fully buffered streams

This should be fairly apparent from the descriptions above.  If the stream is unbuffered then `std::endl` doesn't do any extra work; there is no buffer to flush.  If the stream is line buffered, then writing a newline will flush the buffer anyway, so `std::endl` doesn't do anything extra.  Only for a fully buffered stream does `std::endl` do any extra work.

---

> how cout is not a fully buffered stream?

The C++ language doesn't specify the buffering strategy used for `std::cout`, but most implementations use either no buffering or line buffering when the program's standard output stream is hooked up to a terminal.  If stdout is redirected to something else, like a file, many implementations will switch to using a fully buffered stream for `std::cout`.

Comment: It was a lot helpful, thanks a lot! But how can i assume that cout is using a particular buffering strategy when im printing somethig on windows console.

Comment: and in second last paragraph you wrote , "writing a newline will flush the buffer anyway" , do this newline means a new statement in source code?

Comment: _"how can i assume that cout is using a particular buffering strategy"_. 
 You should assume the std iostreams are fully buffered and flush them when it matters.  Keep in mind that by default `std::cout` is tied to `std::cin` such that `std::cout` will automatically be flushed when a read is requested from `std::cin`.

Comment: _"do this newline means a new statement in source code?"_ No, it means writing an end-of-line marker (i.e. a `'\n'` character) such that the output device moves down to the next line.  `std::endl`  both writes a newline and flushes the output stream (regardless of the buffering mode used).

Comment: Ok. To make it more clear, kindly explain the flushing process of the following, "cout<<"something\nsomething"<<endl;"

Comment: should we assume with the end of each cout statement (without invoking any explicit flushing command), the buffer is automatically flushed?

Comment: In that specific example `std::cout` is flushed by `std::endl`.  That's what `std::endl` does: print a newline and then flush the buffer.  In general, no, you cannot assume that `std::cout` will actually print anything until you perform some operation that forces it to flush its buffer.  That usually means calling its `flush` member function, writing `std::endl` or performing an operation on a tied stream (which `std::cin` is by default).

Comment: so by your last comment, as far as i have understood, cout flushes its buffer at the end of each cout statement, am i right?

Comment: No, `std::cout << whatever` does not flush the buffer (unless the buffer is full, of course).  As long as `std::cout`'s buffer has space remaining, only specific conditions cause it to be flushed.  The most common things that cause the buffer to be flushed are calling `std::cout.flush()` either explicitly or via a manipulator (i.e. `std::endl` or `std::flush`) or by performing I/O on a tied stream (`std::cout` is tied to `std::cin` and `std::cerr` by default).

Comment: `int i;
 cout<<"begin...";
 for(i=0;i<1000000000;i++);
 cout<<"end"<<endl;`, in this code, "begin..." and "end" should be printed at the same time after a little time, which means first cout do not flushes the buffer, it is flushed at the second cout due to endl (if i'm not wrong). But on my computer, "begin..." prints first, and after a little pause, "end" gets printed. Actually this is the thing which is causing the confusion, extending the talk.

Comment: Again, the C++ language does not specify that `std::cout` is buffered at all.  It may be, or it may not be.  To write code that's portable between different C++ implementations you should generally write you code assuming that `std::cout` is fully buffered, but it may not be on your particular implementation with the specific set of compiler options you provided.

Comment: This all helped me a lot in understanding the concept, thanks a lot for your kind help.